# Eslint Bad Indentation In Array Expressions

Tags: javascript, eslint, prettier

I have a simple array definition and i want it to be in the following syntax:

```
this.selfClosingHtmlTags = [
  'area', 'base', 'br', 'col', 'command', 'embed', 
  'hr', 'img', 'input', 'keygen', 'link', 'meta', 'param', 'source', 'track', 
  'wbr'
]
```

Eslint put one item per line when i saved the file:

```
this.selfClosingHtmlTags = [
  'area',
  'base',
  'br',
  'col',
  'command',
  'embed',
  'hr',
  'img',
  'input',
  'keygen',
  'link',
  'meta',
  'param',
  'source',
  'track',
  'wbr'
];
```

This is my current eslint configuration:

```
{
  "extends": ["fbjs"],
  "rules": {
    "comma-style": ["error", "last"],
    "comma-dangle": ["error", "never"],
    "consistent-return": 0,
    "curly": ["error", "multi-line"],
    "indent": ["error", 2, {
      "CallExpression": {
        "arguments": "first"
      },
      "SwitchCase": 1,
      "ArrayExpression": "first"
    }]
  }
}
```

I also use [prettier](https://github.com/prettier/prettier) with [eslint](https://github.com/eslint/eslint). How can i configure it to follow the syntax that i've shown above?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using [eslint-config-prettier](https://github.com/prettier/eslint-config-prettier) and [eslint-plugin-prettier](https://github.com/prettier/eslint-plugin-prettier) if you're gonna use both prettier and eslint to avoid conflicts between some styleguides and prettier.

As for the formatting, if you're using prettier : forget about manual formatting. The point of that tool is to handle that for you. It might not suit your personal taste sometimes, but it's meant to be predictable and coherent. [See the rationale behind prettier's creation in the introduction.](https://github.com/prettier/prettier)